# Android - Requerying cursor ordered by RANDOM()

Tags: android, random, sql-order-by, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

this may sound like a silly question but Im struggling with it. I am working on a quotes application therefore I want to have my quotes ordered from the database randomly each time the application is started.

I am using CursorLoader and a ViewPager. I am having some buttons (put-to-favourites-button) on the screen, which updates a column in database using content resolver which triggers update() in ContentProvider. Update then causes a requery in order to update the change made. All standard.

**This of course causes to give me rows that are ordered differently because of the order by random() clause,** and causes the screen to "disappear".

*Any idea how to get around this? I really want to keep the random ordering functionality.*

```
class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    cursor.setNotificationUri(resolver, uri);
    return cursor;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int count = db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
    resolver.notifyChange(uri, null);
    return count;
}
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to requery with the same order if you use random order in your query. Randomizing the result in your code should give you the possibility to re-randomize on demand. E.g. if you create list of mappings from cursor rows to your randomized order and you don't update the mapping.

Comment: sorry I didnt understand the second part. I am not doing much with the cursor itself, I am using CursorAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from table ORDER BY RANDOM()");
```

[SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing, as zapl suggested, was to add a column. that would hold myOrder, which would be populated with random values  in onCreate, and then just do a Select with order by myOrder